# Virtual candle script working until comment is posted

Tags: html

I am adapting some code to make a sort of virtual candle part of pages on my website.

It looks and works right until I hit enter, and then I get an error page.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Light a Virtual Candle for Aphrodite</h1>
            <div class="subtitle"></div>
<p><a name="jfb0440498"></a>
<!--h2>Light a Candle</h2-->


<form method="post" action="/hellenicpaganism/theoi/aphrodite/light-a-candle.html#jfb0440498" class="jot-form">

    <fieldset>
    <input name="JotForm" type="hidden" value="b0440498179424bd59e27c18c595f9ab" />
    <input name="JotNow" type="hidden" value="943109066" />
    <input name="parent" type="hidden" value="" />
    
    
    
Purpose: <br />
        <input type="radio" name="title" id="title1_b0440498179424bd59e27c18c595f9ab"  value="Thank you Aphrodite!" CHECKED
            onclick="this.form.elements['content'].value = 'Thank you Aphrodite, for...'">Gratitude
        <input type="radio" name="title" id="title2_b0440498179424bd59e27c18c595f9ab"  value="Hail Aphrodite!"
            onclick="this.form.elements['content'].value = 'Great is Aphrodite, for...';">Praise
        <input type="radio" name="title" id="title3_b0440498179424bd59e27c18c595f9ab"  value="Please, Aphrodite"
            onclick="this.form.elements['content'].value = 'Aphrodite, please help...\n\nFor this, I will...';">Request
    <br />
    <textarea name="content" cols="50" rows="4" id="contentb0440498179424bd59e27c18c595f9ab" onFocus="this.form.elements['content'].value=this.form.elements['content'].value.replace('...',' '); this.form.elements['content'].value=this.form.elements['content'].value.replace('...',' ');">Thank you Aphrodite, for...</textarea><br />
    
  
    
    <div style="float:right;width: 100px;"></div>
    <input tabindex="943109071" name="submit" type="submit" value="Light Candle" />
     
    </fieldset>
</form><a name="jotnavb0440498179424bd59e27c18c595f9ab"></a>
<div class="jot-nav">
    
    Showing candles <b>1</b> to <b>10</b> of <b>785</b> 
    
    | <a href="/hellenicpaganism/theoi/aphrodite/light-a-candle.html?jnb0440498=2#jotnavb0440498179424bd59e27c18c595f9ab">Next</a>
    | <a href="/hellenicpaganism/theoi/aphrodite/light-a-candle.html?jnb0440498=79#jotnavb0440498179424bd59e27c18c595f9ab">Last</a>
    
</div>
    <a name="jcb0440498151172"></a>
    
    </div><a name="jotnavb0440498179424bd59e27c18c595f9ab"></a>
<div class="jot-nav">
    
    Showing candles <b>1</b> to <b>10</b> of <b>785</b> 
    
    | <a href="/hellenicpaganism/theoi/aphrodite/light-a-candle.html?jnb0440498=2#jotnavb0440498179424bd59e27c18c595f9ab">Next</a>
    | <a href="/hellenicpaganism/theoi/aphrodite/light-a-candle.html?jnb0440498=79#jotnavb0440498179424bd59e27c18c595f9ab">Last</a>
    
</div>
```

I'm very new to coding so I reused some code from another website with a similar purpose, with adjustments. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for `<br>`